# How to backup app data in google drive using google drive api

Tags: android, google-drive-api, backup, google-drive-android-api, android-backup-service

How to backup your appdata  and store it into google drive through google drive api. 
As an example like whatsapp is using google drive api for storing user data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are happy to answer specific programming questions but please note this is not a tutorial site. Your question as it stands is extremely broad. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for which questions are appropriate.

Comment: Check this, they have good example for uploading files to drive https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo

Comment: @Stormbuster thanks for the reply but this example is for mostly uploading in the drive.

Comment: This is what you want https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro